# RabbitMQ @RabbitListener annotation not working in Spring (not spring-boot)

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am trying to implement rabbitmq in my spring-core developed application. Below is my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is my RabbitConfiguration java file

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME="MyQueue";
    public static final String EXCHANGE_NAME="My_EXCHANGE";


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME,false);
    }


   @Bean
   MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(myQueue());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new RabbitMQListner());
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

}
```

And here is my service class from where I am trying to use the rabbit

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.ExchangeTypes;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
@Component
public class MessagingService{
    public void send(String msg){
        template.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME,msg);
    }


    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void receiveMessage(String car)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello"+car);
    }
    @Bean
    private ApplicationContext context(){
        return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RabbitConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Bean
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(){
        return context().getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    protected AmqpTemplate template;
```

The send method works just fine. But the @Listener annotated method does not work. It does not listen.
What I also tried, I created another config file and annotated with @EnableRabbit, but no benefits. Is there any secret sausage to make it working?

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.EnableRabbit;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends RabbitConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myRabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to see if that helps; if not, post your project someplace so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: How to enable debug logging? I am already running on debug mode in IntelliJ. Unfortunately, I can not share the full source code. But this is all the codes that is handling the rabbitmq. to be more specific the send method can push messages to the queue without any issues but the listener annotation does not work. It does not listen or trigger the method where I apply the annotation.

Comment: I have tried with sample spring boot project and there it works without any issue. Why it is not working in my spring-core project, can't figure it out.

Comment: Refer to your logging subsystem (log4j, logback etc) for how to configure DEBUG logging; enable it for `org.springframework`. `@EnableRabbit` and the container factory is all you need. I can't help further unless you can share a small verifiable project that exhibits the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

i hope you already resolved this issue, here is what i think if its not resolved.
You don't need to use SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory or SimpleMessageListenerContainer class when you use @RabbitListener. in SimpleMessageListenerContainer config class you mapped RabbitMQListner class for listening but you are trying to listen msg in MessagingService class. in SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory you hvnt set the messagelistener itself.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the code is creating its own container factory, `myRabbitListenerContainerFactory`, but @RabbitListener by default listens  to `rabbitListenerContainerFactory`.

Try with `@RabbitListener(queues = "foo", connectionFactory="myRabbitListenerContainerFactory")`

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/RabbitListener.html